# How should I return 404 from a JsonResult Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

In ASP.NET MVC5 I have a controller with a `JsonResult` return type.

Depending on parameters I want to return a 404, as this is descriptive of the user requesting non-existent data.

I could `throw new HttpException(404, "message")` but this feels dirty given the `return HttpNotFound()` syntax. This doesn't work, of course, because `HttpNotFoundResult` does not inherit `JsonResult`

How should I cleanly return 404's from `JsonResult` controller methods?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All your actions should simply have `ActionResult` return values. This allows you to return any valid result type, whether that's a `JsonResult` or `HttpNotFoundResult`.

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    if (!foos.Any())
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    return Json(foos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I'd be careful with saying they "should" because it's really a matter of styling and necessity. Arguing all actions should return ActionResult is like arguing all methods should return `object`.